# Unable to connect with Atlas cluster using PyMongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-atlas, pymongo-3.x

I have been trying to make Pymongo work with my free atlas cluster since a while now, but just reaching errors like:

```
    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
    pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed,connection closed,connection closed, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 60b3d56c099a114d04aa3b66, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('sandbox-shard-00-00.r2jpi.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('connection closed')>, <ServerDescription ('sandbox-shard-00-01.r2jpi.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('connection closed')>, <ServerDescription ('sandbox-shard-00-02.r2jpi.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('connection closed')>]>
    I am not sure what is causing this. Yes, my IP is whitelisted, and yes my Atlas database has a user with proper privileges. All the functions which involve communicating with the server seems to be failing.
```

If i just run:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime

client = MongoClient(
    'mongodb://<username>:<pw>@sandbox.r2jpi.mongodb.net/test?authSource=admin&replicaSet=atlas-jexqkj-shard-0&readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=true')
db = client.sample_mflix
print(db)
```

I get:

```
Database(MongoClient(host=['sandbox-shard-00-02.r2jpi.mongodb.net:27017', 'sandbox-shard-00-00.r2jpi.mongodb.net:27017', 'sandbox-shard-00-01.r2jpi.mongodb.net:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, retrywrites=True, w='majority', authsource='admin', replicaset='atlas-jexqkj-shard-0', ssl=True), 'sample_mflix')
```

OS: Windows 10

Python version: 3.9.2

PyMongo version: 3.9.0

Below is the code I am trying to run (one that results in serverTimeOutError)

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime

client = MongoClient(
    'mongodb://<username>:<pw>@sandbox.r2jpi.mongodb.net/test?authSource=admin&replicaSet=atlas-jexqkj-shard-0&readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=true')

db = client.sample_mflix
trying = db.trying

personDocument = {
    "name": {"first": "Alan", "last": "Turing"},
    "birth": datetime.datetime(1912, 6, 23),
    "death": datetime.datetime(1954, 6, 7),
    "contribs": ["Turing machine", "Turing test", "Turingery"],
    "views": 1250000
}
trying.insert_one(personDocument)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atlas clusters use SRV records to determine the DNS records for each shard / replicaset.

As such you need to connect using a connection string starting `mongodb+srv://`.